# How to connect powerBI with databricks?

Tags: powerbi, databricks

Is there a way to connect databricks to PowerBI, to make graphs over delta tables.

Comment: Yes https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/integrations/bi/power-bi